# I don't know why the correct answer isn't coming up

Tags: python-3.x

I'm novice programmer.
I want the smallest of the input values ​​to be output, but I don't know what's wrong.

Input example :

10

10 4 2 3 6 6 7 9 8 5

Output example :
2

```
n = int(input())    
a = input().split()
min=a[0]

for i in range(n) :
  if a[i] < min :
    min = a[i]
print(min)
```

what is the problem? please help me

Comment: `min` is a python built in you should name it something else

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work (and it does for me).

Nevertheless, `min` is a reserved Python word. Taking that into consideration, I also recommend the following changes for it to be more idiomatic:

```py
a = input().split()
min_num = a[0]

for element in a:
  if element < min :
    min = element

print(min)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be either number or strings. For example "2" is different from 2.

The function split returns an array of strings. You would need to convert each to a number if you want to do number comparison, like:

```
n = int(input())
a = input().split()
min=int(a[0])

for i in range(n) :
  if int(a[i]) < min :
    min = int(a[i])
print(min)
```

Note: you already did that for n (first line in original code), but you did not do the same when you access a.

Answer (score 0):

So, `min` is actually a python built-in, which would be very useful in this scenario. Also, you are not making the input values in `a` into integers, so we can do that too:

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))

print(min(a))
```

We use `map` to turn all the values from the split list into integers, then turn the map object back into a list. Then, using `min`, we can find the smallest number very easily, without a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert each element to integers before comparing them.

```py
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Your code should work, but it will compare strings against strings instead of integers against integers.